# Inheritance and pointer arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, inheritance

If I have a class that inherit from 2 different classes and I want to put the new class into an array. The array hold pointers to only one of the inherit classes. Will that array overflow or will the pointer-array only “contain” the part of the class that inherit from the class the array is made for?

Example:

I have a class called 'screens' it has 3 arrays of pointers to hold reference to other objects.

```
        class Screens
{
        protected:

        //Edit these to fit the amount of elements used to save space :-) Then we don't need to use dynamic (8 bit MCU :-()
        #define NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS 10
        #define NUMBER_OF_GRAPHS 10
        #define NUMBER_OF_TXTS 10

        UTFT *scr;
        UTouch *touch;

        ButtonTft *buttons[NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS];
        GraphTft *graphs[NUMBER_OF_GRAPHS];
        TFT_printer *texts[NUMBER_OF_TXTS];

        uint8_t ellementsButtons;
        uint8_t ellementsGraphs;
        uint8_t ellementsTexts;

        uint8_t addButIndex;
        uint8_t addGrafIndex;
        uint8_t addTxtIndex;


        public:
        Screens(UTFT *_screen);
        void addButton(ButtonTft *but);
        void addGraphs(GraphTft *graf);
        void addText(TFT_printer *txt);
        void printScreen(uint8_t textToPrint = ALL_TXT, graphIDs_e graphToDraw = ALL_GRAPS);
        void printButton(uint8_t index,bool presed = false);
        void printButton(buttonIDs_e buttonID,bool presed = false);
        void printGraph(graphIDs_e graphMode = ALL_GRAPS,bool whatToClear = WHOLE_GRAPH);
        void printTxt(uint8_t txtMode = ALL_TXT);
        ButtonTft* getButton(buttonIDs_e buttonID);
        uint8_t getButtonIndex(buttonIDs_e buttonID);
        ButtonTft* getPressedButton(uint8_t x,uint8_t y);
        GraphTft* getGraph(graphIDs_e graphID);
        GraphTft* getPressedGraph(uint8_t x, uint8_t y);
    `};
```

Then I have another class called “button” that is a button on a screen.

```
#define PRESSED true

    class ButtonTft
    {
        public:
        ButtonTft(UTFT *TFTdisplay, int xTopL,int yTopL, int xButR, int yButR,buttonIDs_e buttonID);
        ~ButtonTft();
        void drawButton(bool pressed = false);
        void setPos(int x, int y);//This is never used... remove?
        void text(char *txt);
        bool isPressed(uint16_t x, uint16_t y);
        buttonIDs_e getButtonID();

        protected:

        buttonIDs_e _buttonID;
        uint16_t xTopLeft;
        uint16_t yTopLeft;
        uint16_t xButRight;
        uint16_t yBotRight;
        char    *butonText;
        uint16_t color;
        UTFT    *scr;
    };
```

Buttons are added to the screen likes this:

```
/*==============================================================================
| Function Name: addButton
|   Description: Adds a button element to the screen.
|         Input: A pointer to the button element
|        Return: -
*=============================================================================*/
void Screens::addButton(ButtonTft *but)
{
    buttons[addButIndex++] = but;//Add the element to the array
    if (addButIndex == NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS+1) addButIndex = 0;//Should not do this. Avoid adding more than 10! But Safety first!
    if(ellementsButtons++ == NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS+1) ellementsButtons = NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS;//Safety first!
}
```

And the function is called with a reference to a button object:

```
module5.addButton(&backButton);
```

Now I want to make a new class called 'modules', it inherits from both 'screens' and 'button'. My idea was that the module IS a button that HAS a screen with it.

```
class Modules : public Screens , public ButtonTft
{
 public:
    Modules(UTFT *_display, int xTopL,int yTopL, int xButR, int yButR, buttonIDs_e buttonID);
    bool isConected;
 protected:
};
```

I pass the constructor arguments to the inherited class like this:

```
 Modules::Modules(UTFT *_display, int xTopL,int yTopL, int xButR, int yButR, buttonIDs_e buttonID) : Screens (_display) , ButtonTft (_display, xTopL, yTopL, xButR, yButR, buttonID)
{
    isConected = 0;
}
```

I would like to collect all the modules into a screen object, which means, I would like to put the modules into the button-pointer-array in the 'screen'-object. (Since the modules inherit from the buttons.) I would also like to add other buttons to the 'module'-object as it also inherit from the screen-class.

```
Modules module5(&display,10,75,100,100,MODULE_5);
module5.addButton(&backButton);
mainScreen.addButton(&module5);
```

If I add new objects (like new buttons) to my module-object and then add that object to a screen, will the button-reference-array in the screen class overflow?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why Modules should inherit from ButtonTft. That would add unnecessary data to Modules. If you need to access protected members of ButtonTft from Modules (which would be bad programming), then make it a friend. The array will not overflow unless you put too many elements into it.

Comment: I might be astray here but my thought was that each module in the system always have a button and a screen associated with it. My idea was that i could collect these (a button and a screen) into a class of its own called a module. I could then show each module as a button on a different screen and show all the modules data in its own screen (hence a screen and a button for each module). Is it a bad idea to do it like that or should i just make a module class that has a reference to a screen and a button?  Thanks for the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are asking, then no. The arrays only hold pointers, which are of fixed size. It should work fine, although it seems like a convoluted way to do things.